# Get TreeViewer in RCP from another Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm working at a Plugin for a Eclipse-RCP. There is another Plugin with a TreeViewer and I want to select an Item from my Plugin. I don't know how to get access it, is this even possible?

I think can get the correct view with:

```
IViewReference home;
    IViewReference [] viewRefs = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
    for (int i = 0; i < viewRefs.length; i++) {
        if(viewRefs[i].getId()==myid){
            home = viewRefs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
```

But home is not a TreeViewer and I cant cast it. How can I get the TreeViewer?

```
home.getTreeViewer() //Doesn't work cause of casting issues
```

I am a newbie to rcp, so I would be nice for some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find your view using:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.findView("your view id");
```

You can then cast the view part to your view class and call a method that you write on that class:

```
if (viewPart != null) {
   MyViewClass myViewPart = (MyViewClass)viewPart;

   myViewPart.getTreeViewer();
}
```

where `MyViewClass` is your `ViewPart` class. You will have to write the `getTreeViewer` method.

If the view is not currently open you can use `showView`:

```
viewPart = page.showView("your view id");
```

Comment: if I make page.findView(id), I get null in return, but I debugged it and saw that in page is a View with the correct id

Comment: Well is the view actually open? If it isn't open you will have to use `showView` instead - see updated answer. findView definitely works if the view with that id is open.

Comment: Show us the `org.eclipse.ui.views` declaration of the view in the plugin.xml and what id you are using in `findView`.

Comment: showView() worked with the same id, but the same view get open as I already have. I will try to solve this problem. I make a Plugin for another Program and I don't have access to the source code and the plugin.xml for the other view. The Documentation is also not complete

Comment: This solution is for Eclipse 3.x. Cannot apply for 4.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `home` to the type of your other view. Then you can get the TreeViewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ViewPart directly from your active `IWorkbenchPage` using `IWorkbenchPage#findView(java.lang.String)`.

If you have the object you want to be selected, get the View's Site, get the Site's selection provider, and then tell the selection provider what should be selected (with a `StructuredSelection` instance containing the object). This only works if the tree, or whatever is in the part (you shouldn't have to care or know that it's a tree), actually contains the object that you're telling it to select.